# How to animate tableview cells constraints when tableview is in and not in editing mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, autolayout

What I am trying to achieve is this: I have a tableview with multiple sections but for clarity here we will just say it has one section. When the tableview is not editing, I want the tableview cell to be laid out one way. Then, when the user hits the edit button, I want the tableview cell to look another way. So pretty much I want the tableview cell to look 1 of 2 ways depending upon whether or not the tableview is in editing mode. I already have the tableview cell constraints working fine if it is not in editing mode. So how can I make my cell flip flop between the 2 sets of constraints? I tried removing the old constraints and implementing the new constraints, but for some reason it's not working. It might be because my constraints are wrong, but am I at least going in the correct direction with what I'm trying to complete here?

Comment: Are you calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` on your cells after you update all of your constraints?

Comment: Yes i am using the [UIView animate..] method and calling set needs layout and layout if needed in there. So it seems like i am going in the correct direction here. Ill keep playing around with it and see what happens. Do you have any other ideas?